# Twig for Django

Tags: django-templates, django-template-filters

I am looking for Twig documentation for Django and I haven't found much. I have read about Twig for PHP especially for Symfony 2. I have some queries about Twig, for instance:

1. I would like do a loop over an array like `{% for i in range(5) %}`, but it doesn't work for me.
2. Is there a filter to capitalize words, like `| upper` or `| lower`. Maybe `ucfirst` or `wcword`? I am a PHP programmer, and this is what I'm used to.
3. I have been trying to work with `static` in my templates. I have tried `{% load static %}`, but when I include a static element like a javascript file or stylesheet, for instances, `<script href="{{ static "js/file.js"}}" ></script>`, Django always throws an exception related to rendering it.

Answer (score 18):

It only makes sense that you haven't found any documentation for using Twig with Django because there is none! Twig is a PHP templating engine that uses a syntax similar to the Django templating system. This is the source of your confusion, from what I see.

Check out the [Django templating system documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) for the actions you want to perform.